# Replace select image on 1 place in array

Tags: javascript, base64, filereader

I have image array.
[image]

I want to move the selected image to the 1st place in the array by clicking
[image]

[image]

```
$(document).on('click', '.newProductPic', function () {

$(".newProductPic").removeClass("selectImage");

$(this).addClass("selectImage");

var image = $(".selectImage")[0];
var fReader = new FileReader();

fReader.onloadend = (function (f) {
    return function (e) {

        var base64ImageString = this.result;
        var imageName = f.name;
        imagesListContent.push({ base64ImageString, imageName });

        addThumbMainImage(base64ImageString, f.name);
        currentMainImage = 'newProductPic' + i + '';
    };
})(image);

fReader.readAsDataURL(image);
var temp = $(".newProductPic")[0];

imagesListContent[0] = imagesListContent[selectMainImageId];

imagesListContent[selectMainImageId] = temp;
});
```

I'm getting a mistake:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
What am I doing wrong and what are the solutions to this problem?

Comment: `image = $(".selectImage")[0]`, it's a jQuery object, taken from the DOM. The _file_reader expects a file to read, not a DOM element.

Comment: If `.newProductPic` refers to an `input type="file"`, then you can just use [`this.files[0]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files) to grab the file.

Comment: @JeremyThille, ohh, I'm a fool. Can you tell us how we can solve this problem in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument  you supply to the readAsDataURL should be a file reference than a jquery object.

```
<input type="file" id="files">


document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, fals)
```

The function will receive the event as an argument and you can get the file reference by `event.currentTarget.files`. This is an array

Another method is to get the file reference from the files array of the input element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL